# Show new Jquery UI Tab after creating it

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I am trying to get a jQuery UI tab to show (open the panel associated with the tab) in the browser when a user adds a new tab. Currently this is what my tab addition functions looks like.

```
let tabs = $("#tabs")
        .tabs({
            heightStyle: "content",
        })
        .on("click", ".delete-tab", function () {
            let panelName = $(this).closest("li").children('a').text();
            $('#deleteLocationModal').addClass('open');
            $('.locationNameHere').text(panelName);
            tabDelete = $(this).closest("li");
            deleteLocationNum = $(this).attr('data-locNum');
            console.log(deleteLocationNum);
        });

let locationNum = 1; //Tracks the number of tabs created, NOT the number of tabs on the screen

/**
 * Create a new tab
 * Create a new panel
 */
$("#addTab").on("click", function (evt) {
    /*addTab();*/
    locationNum++;
    let newTab = (generateTab(locationNum));
    $("#tabs").find("#addTab").before(newTab);
    let newPanel = (generatePanel(locationNum));
    $("#tabs").append(newPanel);
    $('#tabs').tabs("refresh");
    evt.preventDefault();
});

function generateTab(num) {
        return '<li class="tab"><a href="#location_' + num + '">New Location</a> <span data-locNum="' + num + '" class="delete-tab">&times;</span></li>';

    }
```

I have tried looking at the documentation but its not really clear on what the command to show a tab on creation of any tab would be.

Comment: where is the **generateTab** function code?  May you ad your html?

Comment: Let me add that in.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery selector rather than the actual DOM element or manipulate the tabs object to set a certain tab as the active one.

**using jQuery selector:**

```
function generateTab() {
  return $('<li>Some Tab</li>');
}
```

and then

```
$tab = generateTab();
$tab.someFocusFunction();
```

**directly modifying the tabs object:**

```
$('#tabs').tabs({ 
  active: $tab.attr('id');
});
```

Comment: The before() adds the tab I thought

Comment: And it seems to be adding the tab and working when I click it.

Comment: You are right about the `before` function. edited the answer to not include the note anymore.

Comment: The only problem I have with this as it is written for my code is that tab itself is a string UNTIL it is placed with the BEFORE. It doesn't actually contain an actual reference to the object that the before() command creates.

Comment: I don't think this really works, because I have even simulated a click with a trigger('click') and making a top.alert('tab was clicked'). It is somehow going to that anchor and not showing a rewrite to that.

Comment: Your problem with the string is exactly what you can solve by creating a jquery object rather than just the string, as i tried to explain in my answer. See https://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-html-attributes. Note that this object can also be used in the before command.